# Regex - name validation

Tags: regex, expression

I am looking for a regular expression to check names. I have searched the net and also used the suggestion that were given me by StackOverflow while posting this question.

I also know it's possible in stages, but I'm looking for a regex-1-liner to keep my code clean, simple and most important: fast.

What do I need:
A regular expression that checks names of people while they are registering to my site. I want to allow names as:

- Name
- Name surename
- Name O'brian
- Name surename secondarysurname
- Name surename-surnametwo
- N. Surename

But I don't want to allow names as:

- Name  (double spacebar)
- Name -- surename (double minus)
- Name--' (just bullshit)

Well, I think you understand what I mean and what I don't want to allow.

I only want to use a-zA-Z and - . '
I think that's the only thing I need to allow. The - . ' signs can only be used once between or after a word. Since a name like 'name O''Brian' does not exist.

But a name like 'Name surename secondary-thirdsurname' should be allowed. So one spacebar and one minus sign.

I came up with several regex' using http://public.kvalley.com/regex/regex.asp and other regex programs. But I'm just a noob with regex'.

I hope somebody knows a lot about regular expressions and is willing to help me. Because at the moment.. I'm stuck :(

Thanks in advance,

Jelmer

ps. If you have any questions regarding my question. Please ask them because I'd really like to have your help!

Comment: This is a terrible idea. There's a huge array of characters that may well appear in names, that you're currently excluding. åäöüñç... names aren't regular.

Comment: @DavidHedlund: Exactly. See also [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I know I have to allow those too. (My own name has a ö ) but first I just need the basic understanding of how to accomplish this :) But do you have any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general rule of thumb that applies to many aspects of coding, but especially to regex design, is, your code can be:

1. Simple
2. Clean
3. Fast

**Pick two.**

In addition to that, I guarantee that a one-liner this complex will never be clean. Break it up into regex variables and comment it liberally. Later on, you'll be thankful that you did! While you're at it, turn it into a generic name validator class that you can reuse. While Perl can be quite munged by experts into something totally unholy, it's beauty often comes out when we follow the same laws of politeness and cleanliness that we follow in other, more structured languages.

**TL;DR: Don't make it a one-liner. Please.**

Answer (score 0):

this is not bulletproof but should give you a hint in the right direction

```
([a-zA-ZáéíóúñÑ]+ ?'?-?)+
```

UPDATE: Heres a better approach according to @Tim s suggestion

```
([a-zA-ZáíóúñÑö]+( |'|-)?)+
```

Comment: Wonderful. So `Joe '-O- '-` passes as valid, but `William Henry Gates III.` burns out your CPU.

Comment: In case my comment was too cryptic, read this article about [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: did you even read my comment: "this is not BULLETPROOF but should give you a HINT"  (Hint.- a helpful piece of advice or practical suggestion)

Comment: This is *way* worse than "not bulletproof". This is more like advising someone who wants to know how much gas they have in their car's fuel tank to look inside it using a lit match...

Comment: im testing my second answer(which by the way is quite close to the original, and took less than a minute to correct) with the quickrex plugin for eclipse on a below average CPU, with a >2000 char string that ends with an invalid char(thats way more than any real name AFAIK), and believe me, no CPUs have been harmed, and it takes less than a second to evaluate(its just a few millis, so i dont want to waste my time on a serious benchmark). Even if internally it took a lot of steps i would hardly call this catastrophic or "way worse" than anything.

Comment: Did you make sure that the *entire* string is evaluated (which would be a requirement if the regex is supposed to validate a string as opposed to finding a substring)? Your first regex takes about 55 *million* steps of the regex engine on the test string `William Henry Gates III.`; the second one is even worse (63 million steps, and those are regex engine steps, not CPU cycles).

Comment: Check it out by yourself   final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-ZáíóúñÑö]+( |'|-)?)+");
  final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("William Henry Gates III.");
  long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
  matcher.matches();
  System.out.println("It took " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start) + " ms");
 And, if it takes internally a gazillion steps: who cares? ... Algorithms are for people who dont know how to buy more hardware. BTW, are you at any point planning to answer the original question?

Comment: Hey, if you don't care if your code turns up on the Daily WTF one day, be my guest. I still say it's a disastrous regex (made even worse by the edit). Even if you fixed it against catastrophic backtracking like this `(?:[a-zA-ZáíóúñÑö]++[ '-]?)+`, it would still be the wrong approach to the problem. As @DavidHedlund noted, trying to validate a name (by regex or otherwise) is at best futile, at worst a proven way to scare customers away.

Comment: sure it COULD be inefficient if the input wasn´t limited to say 150 or so characters (were talking about names not random input). in the real world it takes a few ms, nobody notices, we carry on with our lives... if we insist on premature optimization we end up with code thay nobody but us can mantain, and usually has hidden bugs. My point is theres no single best answer for every case, but IMO its better to have a less than ideal solution that WORKS and is dead easy to mantain. I have in the past scared more customers with overcomplicated solutions. Means more $$$